# Convert svg in to a pdf, canvas or png image without new library

Tags: javascript, html, svg

i'm trying to get an image or a pdf of a svg image, but i don't want to use other library. At this moment my code is this:

```
        this.html.append(this.printButton);
        this.printButton.click($.proxy(function () {

        const svg = document.getElementById('canvas').innerHTML;
        const blob = new Blob([svg.toString()]);
        const element = document.createElement("a");
        element.download = "visualPlan.svg";
        element.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        element.click();
        element.remove();

        }, this));
```

This code work but the only problem is that it requires an svg file which remains very inconvenient for the end user.
Somebody can help me please?

Comment: _"only problem is that it requires an svg file"_ - I have no idea what you mean by that. If you want to create an image _of_ an SVG - then how should that work, if you don't want to supply any SVG in the first place?

Comment: from an svg file to png

Comment: [direct svg to canvas to png conversion](http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/8187844)